# destiny vanguard will it be able to work on more then one account on ps4

Tags: technical-issues, destiny

I got the destiny ps4 bundle and it was European so the vanguard dlc that came with it isn't working because my main account is an American one, if I create a new European account and use the code on it will I be able to switch my account and get it to work on my American account?

Answer (score 2):

No, the code is bound to your European account and will not work on any other account on your console.

I tried it with a friend's account, who has no code and he logged in on my PS4. It didn't work. Both where European accounts.